# What programs can I use to improve network performance?

Tags: performance

What programs are available to see the performance of my pc? My internet seems to be loading very slow and I have a business internet connection. I ran the command `lshw -C network` and this is what I got:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 50:46:5d:ae:2b:cd
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.5.0-21-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.218 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fdefc000-fdefffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 03
   serial: 6c:f0:49:e3:37:f6
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:50 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fd9ff000-fd9fffff memory:fd9f8000-fd9fbfff memory:fd900000-fd91ffff
```

Comment: I got this back when I installed axel.

Comment: E: Option -a requires an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For internet speed testing, you can try [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net)
However, that can be inaccurate. The best way to tell is get axel or another download accelerator and download a large file to `/tmp` and check the speed like that.

```
sudo apt-get install axel 

axel 'http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=latest' > -a -o /tmp
```

If the download is faster than normal browsing, the problem may be DNS lookup. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Then what do I do? too improve what ever is wrong?

Comment: @user116943 It depends on what's wrong.

Comment: No I'm not behind a proxy. I found out whats wrong. two programs were running at the same time, and making it go slow.

Comment: @user116943 Glad you did. In regards to axel, Ask Ubuntu was removing the line break. It should work fine now and you can use that to test stuff in the future. The /tmp folder should clear itself upon a reboot but you can remove the downloaded file manually if you wish.

Comment: Thank you. Moderators I 'm just being nice and polite, please don't downvote me for saying thank you. I already voted up his replies.